# CGI::Application param() not setting

Tags: perl, templates, param, cgi-application, perl-html-template

I have a piece of code that uses [`CGI::Application`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aApplication) as its base, but something is not working correctly.

When I try to set something via `$Template->param()` it seemingly does not set.
`$Template` is equal to `$self->load_tmpl($template);`

And the piece I want to save is:

```
$Template->param('symbols' => \%a_hash_ref);
```

I know `\%a_hash_ref` contains the expected value. It has a similar form:

```
{'symbol' => 'DTX'},{'symbol' => 'QFLD'}
```

Also, if I do

```
$Template->param('Hey!xD' => 'Something');
```

it doesn't save, but

```
$Template->param($Pagination);
```

does, where `$Pagination` is also a hash_ref.

I know all the values are what they should be, and I also tried it with some simple strings, which should work, but they are not set. I know this because when I run:

```
my @params = $Template->param();
die Dumper \@params;
```

it outputs all the variables it should have set, but the expected ones(including the `'Hey!xD'` string) are missing. I also know it actually runs the code, because this die Dumper is after I try to set the values.

The template file contains this piece of code:

> $(document).ready(function () {  mainFunction('[%symbol%]'); 
>                   });

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what is being given to the param:

> [
>             {
>               'date' => '2006-07-05',
>               'avg_gain' => undef,
>               'bollinger_mid' => '32.80000',
>               'symbol' => 'BBQ'
>             },
>             {
>               'date' => '2006-04-04',
>               'avg_gain' => undef,
>               'bollinger_mid' => '34.55656',
>               'symbol' => 'AAPL'
>             }
>             ...
>   ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a HTML::Template problem, which CGI::Application uses by default for templating.

Do you perhaps have `die_on_bad_params` set to 0 in your `load_tmpl` call? HTML::Template should by default die if you try to set a parameter that doesn't exist in the loaded template ([docs here](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTemplate#Error-Detection-Options)). When `die_on_bad_params` is disabled, you'll get the behavior you're describing, where an unknown template param is ignored and discarded.

Additionally, [according to the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTemplate#TMPL_LOOP), `TMPL_LOOP` takes an arrayref of hashrefs as its `param` argument. Maybe it would help to pass your "symbols" parameter like this:

```
my $symbols = [{ symbol => 'DTX' },{ symbol => 'QFLD' }];
$Template->param(symbols => $symbols);
```

If you post a sample template and small script that shows the error it'll be easier to tell for certain.

Comment: Yes, I have it set to 0! Thanks! If it will die when I try to set a param that doesn't yet exist on the template, how can I set that param then?

I read the docs and I don't see why $Template->param('symbols') does not exist. In my template I have this:

< TMPL_LOOP NAME = "symbols" > fetchQuoteData('[%symbol%]'); < /TMPL_LOOP>

Comment: Hi, I added some `TMPL_LOOP` info from the docs that may help.

Comment: Of course, thank you very much for your help. I do send an arrayref of hashrefs apparently. I'll put the code as an edit

Comment: The mistake was that I had a spaces between < and TMPL_LOOP, so it didn't process it. Thanks anyway! You're awesome ;)

Comment: Glad it works now. I've never used HTML::Template, but it seems really finicky. I know it's not so helpful to recommend other packages/frameworks when you're already invested, but have you considered using [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Intro.pod)? It's a proven and flexible templating system that I've used a great deal. There's a plugin for CGI::App (CGI::Application::Plugin::TT), as well.